# Unable to hit the URL in chrome browser using codedui test

Tags: google-chrome, coded-ui-tests

I have a Coded UI test which works fine in IE but it is not working in Chrome.
I have installed the Selenium component and the Chrome driver.

Using:
Visual Studio version 2013 update 5;
Chrome browser version 66; and,
Chrome driver 2.38

Below is the code which I am using:

```
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
                   BrowserWindow browser = new BrowserWindow();
            browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("Xyz.com"));                        
    }
```

This gives the following error when the above line is executed:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

Can someone help me on this, is there any extra step which I need to follow.

Comment: does it launches the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can say is CodedUI is *pretty bad* in supporting Chrome & Firefox. However Visual Studio 2015 works quiet well with chrome (& firefox).

**Firefox**: Use an older version of firefox & stop it from further upgrading. I use 45.0 & worked well with Visual Studio 2012 & 2015.

**Chrome**: No support in 2012. Works in 2015 after applying a hotfix at : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211422/fix-issues-with-action-recording-using-microsoft-test-manager-and-code

I faced altogether different problem with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.8, more on that later.